# json_encode многомерного массива

Tags: php, json

Доброго времени! Такой вопрос как инкодировать в джейсон многомерный массив? 
вот к примеру это будет так тут есть выборка 10ти значений из БД

и я их в цикле запихиваю в массив так:

```
 $var = array();
 for ($i = 0; $i != $numn; $i++) {
 $get = mysql_fetch_array($tmpn);
 array_push($var,$get['cardnumb']);
 }
```

далее заношу в мессив их

```
 $res = ['par1'] = $var;
```

Ну и вместе с остальными значениями инкодирую

```
echo json_encode($res);
```

получается на выходе что то вроде такого:

```
{"par1":["3011","3012","3013","3014","3015","3016","3017","3018","3019"]}
```

массив как бы есть но он без ключей, а как сделать так не пойму:

```
 {"par1":[{"1":3011,"2":3012,"3":3013,"4":3014,"5":3015,"6":3016,"7":3017,"8":3018,"9":3019}]}
```

то есть с ключами, подскажите пожалуйста как такое сделать?

Comment: Зачем здесь ключи?

Comment: @Ипатьев я просто их с аякса потом ловлю и не знаю как в начальном случае разобрать

Comment: @Ипатьев вот так success: function(html){
   
    var inrate = html.par1; } а двльше как разобрать в таком не могу

Comment: разбирать как обычный массив

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте параметр JSON_FORCE_OBJECT в функции json_encode

```
$r = ["par" => ["test", "test2"]];
echo json_encode($r, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT); //{"par":{"0":"test","1":"test2"}}
```

Это если требуется отправить весь массив как обьект, если же требуется часть, то часть можете преобразовать по сути в обьект (object) и у Вас будет требуемый вывод

```
$r = ["par" => [(object) ["test", "test2"]]];
echo json_encode($r); //{"par":[{"0":"test","1":"test2"}]}
```

По сути, делайте проще, ключи 1,2,3,4,5 и т.д здесь не нужны. Перебирать присланный массив на клиенте можно и без них.