# Как многомерный ассоциативный массив преобразовать в `JSON`, ключ: значение

Tags: php, массивы, json

Как видите в `JSON` файле выглядит не так надо. Я получаю значения с `input`-ов и добавляю в массив и отправляю через `AJAX`. Простой массив знаю как преобразовать, а многомерный нет. Может есть какая то функция? Я пробовал создать массив с "ключами" и в `foreach...` `$taskList [] = array($key[$i] => $phones[$i]);`, но там много мороки, я так и не дошел до конца, и я уверен это не правильно. Подскажите что можно сделать.

---

```
Должно выглядеть так

{
    "user_1": {
        "first_name" : "First Name",
        "last_name": "Last Name",
        "phones" : {
            "phone_1": "****",
            "phone_2": "****",
            "phone_3": "****",
        }
    },
    "user_2": {
        "first_name" : "First Name",
        "last_name " : " fLast Name",
        "phones" : {
            "phone_1": "****",
            "phone_2": "****",
            "phone_3": "****",
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
JSON
    [
        {"user1":[
                ["phone_1 345345","phone_2 5345","phone_3 123"],
                "First Name Michael","Last Name Podlevskykh"]
        },
        {"user2":[
                ["phone_1 345345","phone_2 5345","phone_3 123"],
                "First Name Michael","Last Name Podlevskykh"]
        }
    ]
```

---

`AJAX`

```
$('#form').submit(function(event) {
  var arrPhones= [],
      arrUserInfo = [arrPhones],
      //code arrUserInfo            
  var data='phones='+JSON.stringify(arrUserInfo);
  $.ajax({
    //code
    dataType: 'JSON',  
    data:      data,
    //code       
  });
});
```

---

```
PHP

$phones = (json_decode($_POST["phones"], true));
$file = file_get_contents('new.json');
$taskList = json_decode($file,TRUE); 
$taskList[] = array('user1'=> $phones); // все дело в этой строке, я так понимаю
file_put_contents('new.json', json_encode($taskList)); 
unset($taskList); 

var_dump($phones )

// (
    // [0] => Array
        // (
            // [0] => phone_1 
            // [1] => phone_2 
            // [2] => phone_3 
        // )
    // [1] => First Name 
    // [2] => Last Name 
// )
```

---

Comment: мы то откуда знаем, как вам там надо?

Comment: зы: `var data= { phones: arrUserInfo };`

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/561075/json-encode-многомерного-массива

Comment: я добавил код. вот что я хочу получить. @teran

Comment: Не понятно, как вы собираете объект пользователя. желаемое и полученное - совершенно разные вещи. Может попробуете для начало привести формат данных к правильному виду? Потом для `json_encode` попробуйте использовать константу `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` во втором параметре

Answer (score 1):

**JSON:**

```
{
    "user_1": {
        "first_name" : "First Name",
        "last_name": "Last Name",
        "phones" : {
            "phone_1": "****",
            "phone_2": "****",
            "phone_3": "****",
        }
    },
    "user_2": {
        "first_name" : "First Name",
        "last_name " : " fLast Name",
        "phones" : {
            "phone_1": "****",
            "phone_2": "****",
            "phone_3": "****",
        }
    }
}
```

**Array**

```
array (
      'user_1' => 
      array (
        'first_name' => 'First Name',
        'last_name' => 'Last Name',
        'phones' => 
        array (
          'phone_1' => '****',
          'phone_2' => '****',
          'phone_3' => '****',
        ),
      ),
      'user_2' => 
      array (
        'first_name' => 'First Name',
        'last_name ' => ' fLast Name',
        'phones' => 
        array (
          'phone_1' => '****',
          'phone_2' => '****',
          'phone_3' => '****',
        ),
      ),
    )
```